# Fuzzy match in a column in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, fuzzy

I have a column that has strings. I want to do a fuzzy match and mark those which have an 80% match in a column next to it. I can do it with the following code on a smaller dataset but my original dataset is too big for this to work efficiently. Is there a better way to do this? This is what I have done.

```
import pandas as pd

l = [[1,'a','b','c','help pls'],[2,'a','c','c','yooo'],[3,'a','c','c','you will not pass'],[4,'a','b','b','You shall not pass'],[5,'a','c','c','You shall not pass!']]
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['Serial No','one','two','three','four'])

df['yes/no 2'] = ""

for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, df.shape[0]):
        if (i != j):
            if (fuzz.token_sort_ratio(df.iloc[i,df.shape[1]-2],df.iloc[j,df.shape[1]-2]) > 80):
                df.iloc[i,df.shape[1]-1] = "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

l = [[1,'a','b','c','help pls'],[2,'a','c','c','yooo'],[3,'a','c','c','you will not pass'],[4,'a','b','b','You shall not pass'],[5,'a','c','c','You shall not pass!']]
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['Serial No','one','two','three','four'])

def match(row):
    thresh = 80
    return fuzz.token_sort_ratio(row["two"],row["three"])>thresh


df["Yes/No"] = df.apply(match,axis=1)
print(df)

   Serial No one two three                 four  Yes/No
0          1   a   b     c             help pls   False
1          2   a   c     c                 yooo    True
2          3   a   c     c    you will not pass    True
3          4   a   b     b   You shall not pass    True
4          5   a   c     c  You shall not pass!    True
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Sorry if i wasn't clear before but i want to find the values in the column "four" that exceed the thresh value. Hence in this case, 'help pls' and 'yooo' would be false and others would be true because a variation of them exist in the column. How do I do that?

Comment: @Harry Check the new answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz,process

l = [[1,'a','b','c','help pls'],[2,'a','c','c','yooo'],[3,'a','c','c','you will not pass'],[4,'a','b','b','You shall not pass'],[5,'a','c','c','You shall not pass!']]
df = pd.DataFrame(l,columns = ['Serial No','one','two','three','four']).reset_index()

def match(df,col):
    thresh = 80
    return df[col].apply(lambda x:"Yes" if len(process.extractBests(x[1],[xx[1] for i,xx in enumerate(df[col]) if i!=x[0]],
            scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio,score_cutoff=thresh+1,limit=1))>0 else "No")  


df["five"] = df.apply(lambda x:(x["index"],x["four"]),axis=1)
df["Yes/No"] = df.pipe(match,"five")
print(df)


   index  Serial No one two three                 four                      five Yes/No
0      0          1   a   b     c             help pls             (0, help pls)     No
1      1          2   a   c     c                 yooo                 (1, yooo)     No
2      2          3   a   c     c    you will not pass    (2, you will not pass)    Yes
3      3          4   a   b     b   You shall not pass   (3, You shall not pass)    Yes
4      4          5   a   c     c  You shall not pass!  (4, You shall not pass!)    Yes
```